# why python index() function raises error in case element not present, can't it simply return -1

Tags: python, list

do we Always need to use try catch blocks while finding index of elements, when we are not sure weather the element present or not
or is there any function exists that returns -1.

Comment: [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP)

Comment: It's just a design decision. strings have both `index()` and `find()`, one raises an exception, the other returns `-1`. Lists just have `index()`, and it raises an exception.

Comment: The problem with returning `-1` is that it's a valid index -- negative indexes count from the end. So if you do `l[l.index(3)]` you'll get the last element of the list even if the value isn't found.

Comment: But strings also support negative indexes , isn't that a problem..